# Auto, or semi-automatic disk space management?

Tags: partitioning, lvm, automatic

Is there an automatic method of adding hard drives to an LVM?  I get as far as formatted the second drive in gParted, then the most basic tutorials I find contain a novel's worth of terminal commands.

As you might guess, I'm coming from windows.

I must stress that I am only interested in user-friendly solutions.  So if the only option I have is to sudo apt whatever until I ascend into the stars and become one with skynet or whatever. Then just tell me it's not possible and I'll format the whole thing and walk away.

I do appreciate any responses, but I'm not interested in any solutions if the end result is that basic system usage has to become a full-time job.  And I'm just saying that to save everyone some time.  You do you, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you’re using Ubuntu 20.04, you should be able to do this with exactly five commands in Terminal (six if you want to confirm your volume has grown). There used to be a GUI available, but that was many years ago. As you’re looking for the simplest option, I won’t bore you with the alternatives for Ubuntu derivatives that may work, as I simply don’t know.

That said, as you seem ready to add your new disk to an existing Logical Volume, let’s get it done:

0. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
1. Confirm the name of the Logical Volume that will receive the new disk:

   ```
   sudo lvs
   ```

   This will give you something like:

   ```
   LV   VG      Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
   vol1 wwwdata -wi-ao---- <13.82t
   ```

   ***Note:** You'll see different values for* `LV`, `VG`, *and* `LSize`, *but the gist is the same.*
2. Create a physical volume on your new disk. For the sake of this example, I'll call it `/dev/sdn`:

   ```
   sudo pvcreate /dev/sdn
   ```

   You should see a message like:

   ```
   Physical volume "/dev/sdn" successfully created.
   ```

   ***Note:** This will use* the entire disk. *If you choose to assign just a single partition from a disk, specify the partition name. For example:* `/dev/sdn3`.
3. Add the new disk to your Logical Volume:

   ```
   sudo vgextend wwwdata /dev/sdn
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to replace* `wwwdata` *with the name of the Volume Group that was in the list from step 1. This would be the name under* `VG`.
   So long as everything is good, you will see a message like this:

   ```
   Volume group "wwwdata" successfully extended
   ```
4. (Optional) Confirm the volume has been extended:

   ```
   sudo vgs
   ```

   This will give you something like:

   ```
   VG      #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
   wwwdata   2   1   0 wz--n- <17.82t  4.00t
   ```

   ***Note:** This example uses a 4TB disk as* `/dev/sdn`. *The size of your new disk will appear in the* `VFree` *column, as the space has not yet been assigned to the file system.*
5. We will need to extend the logical volume to fill the new space:

   ```
   sudo lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/wwwdata/vol1
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to change* `wwwdata` *to the name of your Volume Group, which was found in Step 1, and* `vol1` *to your Logical Volume, which was also found in Step 1.*
   When it's done, you'll see a message like:

   ```
   Size of logical volume wwwdata/vol1 changed from X to Y
   Logical volume vol1 successfully resized
   ```
6. Last step! Now that the new disk is part of the Volume Group, grow the file system so that you can actually use the space:

   ```
   sudo resize2fs -p /dev/wwwdata/vol1
   ```

   ***Note:** Again, be sure to replace* `wwwdata` *and* `vol1` *with the values that are correct for your system.*
   The volume will now be resized to fill 100% of the space available. This can be done without rebooting or unmounting partitions, or anything like that.

As you're coming from Windows, this will probably seem like a lot of unnecessary typing. A GUI can abstract a lot of this stuff away, after all. That said, I do hope this mostly-five-step process can solve your problem so that you can do you again